# Product Update with Url_Key & Store_Id Attribute Already Exists error in csv import with magento EE

Tags: catalog, import, csv, ee-1.13.0.2

When i am update product description in my magento enterprise edition, i get the url_key & store_id already exists error in csv import.

Comment: Please give us some more information: Did you check if the url_key exists in the DB (for which store-view)? How many store-views do you have? Which EE version? Did you already do some debugging?

Comment: I have 5 store and URL KEY is already exist. I wants to update products description store wise. I have magento ee 1.13.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before EE 1.13.1.0 there are problems to import products with same names that lead to the same URL key. Upgrade to EE 1.13.1.0 which adds the product ID to the URL Key.

Comment: I think, it's not possible right now. Is there any possibility with this version?

Comment: You can try to backport the change of course or ask EE support to provide you with a custom patch.

Comment: Ok. Alex. Same thing work in Magento's CE. and i had also work with programmatically also but not work.